# how do i detect key movement for discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, mouse

i want to change the status of discord bot whenever i move my mouse every 1 second and i wanna set it to idle if my mouse is not moving

```
`change_status.start();

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def change_status():
    if (mouse move)):
        await client.change_presence(
            status=discord.Status.dnd,
            activity=discord.Game(name=f"Up")
        )
    else:
        await client.change_presence(
            status=discord.Status.idle,
            activity=discord.Game(name=f"Inactive")
        )`
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Here's the code;

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=3)
async def change_status():
    savedpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()

    for i in range(1):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        curpos = win32api.GetCursorPos()


    if savedpos != curpos:
        await client.change_presence(
            activity=discord.Game(name=f""),
            status=discord.Status.dnd,
        )
    else:
        await client.change_presence(
            activity=discord.Game(name=f""),
            status=discord.Status.idle,
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).